How to achieve a shoulder rig?
I keep trying and trying to make a shoulder rig but there is nothing to go off from!
I only have this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=746pinnb3hM
My topology is identical to this one and I can't understand this rig, I've tried and tried but I keep running into annoying Rotation limitations and terrible deformations.
How can I do a shoulder rig like this?

Hello maybe share your file?
